# NullPointerException when using LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to use LocalBroadcastManager with my custom intents.
It seems that it's very picky about intents and If I send the intent this way:

In Myintents.java I declare

```
public static final String LOCATION_UPDATE = "com.example.myapp.location_update";
```

Later on in the broadcast sender I do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyIntents.LOCATION_UPDATE);
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then I'm getting this exception:

```
05-05 02:23:29.914: E/AndroidRuntime(6952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-05 02:23:29.914: E/AndroidRuntime(6952): java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-05 02:23:29.914: E/AndroidRuntime(6952): at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297) 
05-05 02:23:29.914: E/AndroidRuntime(6952): at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)  
05-05 02:23:29.914: E/AndroidRuntime(6952): at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116) 
05-05 02:23:29.914: E/AndroidRuntime(6952): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

However If I use an explicit string

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my-intent");
```

Everything works fine.

What's wrong? Why can't I define the intent name in another class?

Comment: public static final String "LOCATION_UPDATE = (Quote before LOCATION_UPDATE), it that a typo?

Comment: what is the content of "LocalBroadcastManager.java:297"

Comment: No it's not that typo.. LocalBroadcastManager is part of the Android framework. not mine.

Comment: Any progress with this @ApriOri - I too weirdly just started seeing it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just came across this. The NPE is a result of the registered listener (read: receiver) for the event you are firing (MyIntents.LOCATION_UPDATE) not having been instantiated by the component hosting it.

Check that the thing you want to respond to this broadcast has actually been instantiated at the right point (probably the hosting activity/fragment).

Comment: So how to you explain the explicit string issue? I didn't understand why changing inline string to a static final string variable makes any difference.

Comment: I suspect that is owing to the fact that the intent [action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)) was changed from something which another receiver had registered in it's intent filter (i.e. is called when that action is broadcast) to something arbitrary ("my-intent" rather than "com.example.myapp.location_update"). The LocalBroadcastManager found no listeners registered to received "my-intent" actions so nothing happened.

Comment: You can see this in AOSP [here](https://code.google.com/p/moloko/source/browse/libs/ActionBarSherlock/src/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java?r=538#297)

Comment: I was registering receiver before creating an instance of my class.

Comment: I forgot to initialize my instance of the receiver in onCreate. Thanks, this is helpful

Answer (score 12):

In my case, (I had the same error) I forgot to create an instance of my class that extends the BroadcastReceiver. (and overrides the onReceive() method)

```
    private MeasurementUpdateReceiver   m_MeasurementUpdateReceiver;

// Listens to local broadcasts done by the MeasurementService
private class MeasurementUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Intent already filtered by the LocalBroadcastManager in onResume()
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Received data " + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Passing an empty reference of this class to the LocalBroadcastManager with:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(m_MeasurementUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter("measurementupdate"));
```

wasn't a problem until it tries to invoke the onReceive() method of the class. What I forgot was:

```
m_MeasurementUpdateReceiver = new MeasurementUpdateReceiver();
```

I hope this helps other people facing this error.

Comment: I created the receiver in onCreate (of a Fragment) and registered the receiver in onAttach. Got this error, so just make sure you create the receicer in the same place.